# How to resize image inside of a leading property?

Tags: image, flutter

I am trying to add a logo before the title in the App Bar but it seems the image only takes the width and height of the leading property.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  Widget build(context){
      return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title:Text('Hi, Andi Loshi'),
          backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(230, 1, 1,1),
          leading:  new Image.asset("assets/images/logo.png",
          fit:BoxFit.cover,
          height:20.00,
          width:20.00
          ),
        ),
        body: Text('Body will reside here')
      );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Though you can not modify size of leading you can add image before title like below in appbar, title please check below code.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(Home());

class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  Widget build(context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Container(
            child: Row(
              children: [
                Image.asset(
                  "assets/images/logo.png",
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  width: 10,
                ),
                Text('Hi, Andi Loshi')
              ],
            ),
          ),
          backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(230, 1, 1, 1),
        ),
        body: Text('Body will reside here'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: It's my pleasure @MussaKalokola

Answer (score 5):

@Mussa Kalokola you can just wrap the image in leading with padding that will make it smaller.

I think that's the easiest solution for that.

eg.

```
appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text(_getScreenTitle(context, _selected)),
    leading: const Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
      child: ClipOval(
        child: Image(
          image: AssetImage('images/test.png'),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
```

Answer (score 3):

You can wrap your leading widget inside a **Center** Widget or set **leadingWidth** property inside **AppBar**.

example:

```
appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text('Your Title'),
    //leadingWidth: 38.0,
    leading: Center(
        child: Image(
          image: AssetImage('images/test.png'),
        ),
  ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Widgets inside an `AppBar` have limited size. If you want a custom one, you can implement it from scratch, this [article](https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-increase-the-power-of-your-appbar-sliverappbar-c4f67c4e076f) can help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `leadingWidth` property in the `AppBar`.

```
class Home extends StatelessWidget {
Widget build(context){
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title:Text('Hi, Andi Loshi'),
      backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(230, 1, 1,1),
      leading:  new Image.asset("assets/images/logo.png",
      leadingWidth: 80,
      fit:BoxFit.cover,
      height:20.00,
      width:20.00
      ),
    ),
    body: Text('Body will reside here')
  );
```

}
}